# AppConfig from design environment

Tags: c#, app-config

Trying to get the appconfig path from the debug environment for a component but I keep getting nulls errors from this when I build the solution is vs2017.  any help appreciated.

```
       public string GetAppConfigPath()
    {
        var devenv = (DTE)_c.Site.GetService(typeof(DTE));
        var projects = (Array)devenv.ActiveSolutionProjects;
        var activeProject = (Project)projects.GetValue(0);

        foreach (ProjectItem item in activeProject.ProjectItems)
        {

            if (!item.Name.Equals("app.config")) continue;
            var info = new System.IO.FileInfo(activeProject.FullName);
            if (info.Directory != null)

            return info.Directory.FullName + "\\" + item.Name;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: actually I get an index out of range exception from the array

Comment: `(Project)projects.GetValue(0);` - try using `GetValue(1)` - some collections in COM are 1-based instead of 0-based.

Comment: But please post your entire exception details, especially the stack-trace and point out the line number of the exception.

Comment: Tip: you should be using a case-insensitive string comparison here: `item.Name.Equals("app.config")`

Comment: Tried 1, didn't work...  Error happens on that line.  Its a VS error , just a message box shows error when building, can't copy it.  Says Ststem.IndexOutOfRangeExceptions.  Index was outside the bounds of the array at System.Array.InternalGetReference(...

Comment: What happens if you set a breakpoint? Are you able to attach a debugger?

Comment: breakpoints didn't work, had to debug with message boxes.  Ended up doing a hard coded workaround for now, but I need a easy way to set a filename within the projects so that the design time can find the file.